# Select an overloaded non-template function with std::function parameter

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, perfect-forwarding

I have both template and non-template member function overloaded like the code below:

```
struct TypeI {};
using FuncI = std::function<void(TypeI&)>;

struct TypeA {
    
    FuncI m_fn;
    
    TypeA(FuncI const& p_fn = nullptr){
        m_fn = p_fn;
    }
    
};

struct TypeX {
    
    void add_A(int p, FuncI const& p_func) {
        if (!p_func) return;
        //...some code
        add_A(p, TypeA{ p_func });
        //...some code
    }
    
    template<class T>
    void add_A(int p, T&& p_A) {
        this->getGroup(p).add(std::forward<T>(p_A));
        //...some code
    }   
}

int main(){
    
    TypeX x;
    x.add_A(100, [](TypeI& p_I){   //issue: this chooses the template add_A().
        //...some code
    });
    x.add_A(100, [](auto& p_I){    //issue: this chooses the template add_A().
        //...some code
    });
}
```

I need the non-template `add_A()` be selected, but the template version is selected instead.
How to fix this?

Comment: lambdas are NOT `std::function`. template is the exact match.

Comment: In addition, with `T&&` versus `const Obj&`, non-const `Obj&` will also select `T&&` which is an exact match, whereas `const Obj&` requires to add `const`.

Comment: Possible fixes depend of what you want exactly go in template version.

Comment: is it possible to limit the perfect forwarding to specific type only? for this problem i only need it to be `TypeA`. i used perfect forwarding so i can have both copy and move version in one definition. are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Jarod42 but lambdas is convertible to `std::function` right? i currently don't understand how type conversion logic works within overload resolution. i tried reading the docs but i'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-template version is taking `std::function` as parameter, and you're passing lambdas, which requires user-defined conversion. The template version is exact match and wins in overload resolution.

You can impose restriction on the template parameter to make it unusable when object being passed could convert to `FuncI`.

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<T, FuncI>> add_A(int p, T&& p_A) {
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nboAxdCSkuJ55j74)

Comment: is it possible to limit `T` to `TypeA`? i only need to forward the reference for `TypeA` so i can have both `copy` and `move` version in 1 definition. but it seems perfect-forwarding needs generic `T` syntax.

Comment: @acegs Could you explain more about *limit `T` to `TypeA`*? The solution is to make non-template version winning in overload resolution, it's taking `FuncI`, then make the template version unusable with `FuncI`.